# Redhat Multiple Install Disks?

Tags: rhel, system-installation, iso, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install from USB RHEL 4. My supervisor gave me 4 ISO files to use. When I practice using a VM client (using VMware workstation player), it asks for Disk2, but how can I access it?

I do not want to begin install on client machine, without first practising on a VM.

Comment: I moved the info in your comment into the question (you can edit your question as well). I can tell you how to do it in Virtual-box. Hope some one else can help. I will guess: **look for a setting for the virtual CD/DVD, and change it to the new file.**

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I hope that you plan on converting that answer-of-a-comment into a proper Answer? Please & thank you!

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor if you're not comfortable with the partial answer, I'd encourage Mike to take ctrl-alt-delor's comment and turn it into the actual steps you took -- as an Answer. Thank you!

Comment: VMware has a "Change File" Option but still does not show up when prompted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure RHEL4 only ever use the first CD image to install the base system. The other CDs are for exotic packages, sources and extended documentation. Install only the basic system and you only need them when there's no internet connection around, as you can install at that stuff from the online repositories once your base system is up and running. (And should there be no internet connection, you use the supplemental CDs also from within the running system only.)

Comment: @Janka is there a way to avoid the pop up to insert disc 2? it constantly asks then says "cant access CDROM"

Comment: I don't know RHEL4 good enough but try 1) minimal package selection, especially: U.S. English locale only 2) booting from the second CD.

Comment: You might be able to configure a VM to have multiple virtual CDROM drives, and put a different ISO image in each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you how to do it in Virtual-box. Hope some one else can improve this answer.

I will guess: look for a setting for the virtual CD/DVD, and change it to the new file.

Virtual machine settings → Hardware tab → CD/DVD → Use ISO image file → browse

The manual may help.
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-C58B93A7-52CF-456D-95C1-8B5A906C9619.html

Or this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=66&v=QVbtJnGjTYk